# Read file and store it in protected variable in c++

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm trying to read a file and store it in a protected variable. All methods are in the same class.

```
class A: public B
{
  public:
     //method declarations
  protected:
  string d;
};

void A::l(std::string filename)
{
  ifstream ifs;
  ifs.open(filename);
  string d { istreambuf_iterator<char> {ifs}, istreambuf_iterator<char> {} };  
  ifs.close();
 }

 void A::f(void)
 {
   std::cout << d.length()  << std::endl;
 }
```

When I try to print the length of the string, it is 0. When I try to print `d` in f(), nothing is printed. I need `d` to be a protected variable and I cannot change the methods either. How do I pass the read file string to `f` method?

Comment: You store it into a local `string d` inside your `A::l()` method and not in your member `string d`.

Answer (score 1):

You assigned to a local, use the member (`this->` is optional here):

```
this->d.assign(istreambuf_iterator<char> {ifs}, {});
```

If that doesn't help, you're probably specifying the file name wrong.

Try an absolute path (e.g. /home/user/file.txt or C:\Documents\User\Documents\file.txt) **or** check the working directory of your program.

You can always check for errors:

```
if (!ifs) throw std::runtime_error("File could not be opened");
```

Comment: I'm able to read the file contents in `l` method correctly. It is read and stored in `d` variable. But when I try to access it in `f`, the length of `d` is 0.

Comment: Just added that. Sorry for missing that part initially

Comment: Opps you are fast!

Comment: Missing the point. It's not "adding this->". It's removing the local variable declaration

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with the fact that your variable is protected. The problem is that you are defining another variable with the same name. To avoid this problem some people append an underscore to the name of the variables, like 'd_', and other people write 'm_d'. But you don't need to do that if you don't want to.

One way to do what you want to do is the following:

```
class A
{
  public:
  void l(std::string filename);
  void f();

 //method declarations
 protected:
 string d;
```

};

```
void A::l(std::string filename)
{
  ifstream ifs{filename};
  if(!ifs)
      return; // error

  std::copy(istreambuf_iterator<char>{ifs},
        istreambuf_iterator<char>{},
        std::back_inserter(d)); // this is A::d

}
```

You don't need to use 'this->'. In fact in C++ you never use 'this' (only in sentences like 'return *this').

Also, in C++ you don't write:

```
void f(void);
```

but instead, you write

```
void f();
```

And also you don't need to close the ifstream. The destructor is going to do it for you.